# Controlling PolymorphicModel classed object as model in Generic view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-generic-views, django-polymorphic

I have a PolymorphicModel class named Vehicle, and I derived two class from this: Car and Truck.

I use UpdateView to update but it's getting vehicle_id from vehicle_list randomly. And I have to control which type of vehicle is this model. But I couldn't.

My classes:

```
class Vehicle(PolymorphicModel):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, verbose_name="ID")


class Car(Vehicle):
    car_license = models.CharField(max_length=32)


class Truck(Vehicle):
    truck_license = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

In view:

```
class VehicleUpdate(UpdateView):
    car = object
    if car.car_license is not None:
        model = Car
    else:
        model = Truck
    fields = '__all__'

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return reverse_lazy('person-list')
```

But it's giving this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'tr_id'
```

By the way, I tried to use "isinstance()" but it didn't work. Maybe it's about being PolymorphicModel, I don't know.

```
class VehicleUpdate(UpdateView):
    if isinstance(object, Car):
        model = Car
    else:
        model = Truck
    fields = '__all__'

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return reverse_lazy('person-list')
```

Comment: What makes you think you can access attributes like that at class level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code at the class top level (outside a function definition) is executed when the `class` statement is executed - which is, usually (=> when the class is defined at the module's top level), when the module is imported. This means that at this point, `object` is most probably the builtin `object` class, or whatever has been bound to the name "object" previously in the module, and definitly not a `Vehicle` instance.

I seldom use class-based-views (most of the time a plain function view is by far easier to write / read / modify than a CBV) and never use generic CBVs so I can't tell for sure but from the doc it looks like trying to set the class's `model` attribute from the current instance (`self.object` - of course only available from with a method) is not going to work since the mechanism that gets this instance relies on the `model` attribute...

As a side note, if the only difference between you `Car` and `Truck` classes is the name of the licence field, then really it's very poor design as it actually breaks liskov substitution principle for no good reason.